# Truncate datetime column in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a column I am using as part of a select that uses this format (2011-09-28 14:51:59).  How do I remove the time element and just keep the date all within my query?

```
SELECT PictureModifiedDateTime AS FILE_DATE WHERE column = "blah"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

### [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(PictureModifiedDateTime,'%y-%m-%d') AS FILE_DATE WHERE column = "blah"
```

or use date

### [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

```
SELECT DATE(PictureModifiedDateTime) AS FILE_DATE WHERE column = "blah"
```